# Use UIButtom Appearence proxy

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I try to customize UIAlertView

Is it possible use Appearance API to customize button inside UIAlertView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforunately no, you are not able to customize the button appearance on a UIAlertView using UIAppearance.  When it comes to customization UIAlertView can seem a little locked down.  Having said that though there are a few resources out there with examples of people doing what you are saying.  Here on SO there is an answer to a similar question using objective-C.

[Customizing the buttons on a UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828977/customizing-the-buttons-on-a-uialertview)

Converting that to C# for use in Xamarin shouldn't be too hard and would look something like this:

```
var av = new UIAlertView( );
av.AddButton( "" );
var button = av.Subviews.Last( );
button.Hidden = true;

var newButton = new UIButton( UIButtonType.Custom );
av.AddSubview(newButton);
av.Show();

newButton.SetImage(...);
newButton.AddTarget(...);
newButton.Frame = button.Frame;
```

Comment: [*"The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: @vikingosegundo, yes I meant to mention that as well.  But the more I search around, the more I see people messing with it.  Not sure how many of these modifications make it into the app store.  :-)

Comment: I think in iOS 7 you cannot even call `addSubview:` anymore.

Comment: @vikingosegundo that could very well be true.  I was using the Visual Studio intellisense to verify the property and method names, but my SDK version was probably set to an older version.

Comment: I just tried it. you can call it but no view is added.

Comment: `[av setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView];"` works, but is defined private and there-for "illegal".